# What does it mean for the columns of a matrix to be linearly independent?

Tags: determinant

I've just learnt that det(A) = 0 when the columns of a matrix are linearly dependent, but what does that mean? Could you give me an easy to follow example with numbers please?

Thank you!

Comment: The identity matrix has determinant $1$. Linear independence of the columns means that the column vectors of the matrix are linearly independent. You should review this definition (e.g. google "linear independence").

Comment: Oh sorry, honest mistake. Ok thanks

Comment: You mean the determinant is $0$ when the column are linearly *dependent* that is *not* linearly independent.

Comment: @Jess Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 5\\ 2 & 4 & 10\\ -5 & 0 & -25
\end{bmatrix}$ has linearly DEPENDENT columns because the last column can be obtained from the first one only by multiplying by $5$. In this case, the determinant of the matrix is $0$ and so the matrix is not invertible.

Comment: Thanks! This is the kind of answer i was looking for

Comment: @Jess Glad you understood!

Answer (score 2):

By [**definition**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence#Definition) $\{\vec v_i\}$ are linearly independent if

$$\sum a_i \vec v_i=0 \iff a_i=0 \quad\forall i$$